# How to update nested state's nested object property Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
showAllPics(docid){

        console.log(docid)
        var newSelected = Object.assign({},this.state.CompetitorPhotos);

        console.log("b4-->",newSelected[docid]['display']);
        newSelected[docid]['display'] = true;
        console.log("after -->",newSelected[docid]['display'],newSelected);

        console.log(newSelected,this.state.CompetitorPhotos)

        this.setState({ CompetitorPhotos: newSelected },function(){
            console.log(newSelected,this.state.CompetitorPhotos)
        });

    }
```

I am trying to update 'display' property in a nested property of reactjs state.
The following code fails...What am i doing wrong ..

```
    console.log("after -->",newSelected[docid]['display'],newSelected);
    results in "after -->",true, newSelected.docid.display remains false
```

Comment: Object.assign({}) does not deep copy, so you're basically mutating your state when doing newSelected[docid]['display'] = true; You could however use something like : cloneDeep from lodash in order to update your state as needed https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#cloneDeep

Comment: can you make a jsbin / jsfiddle with some dummy data

Answer (score 1):

You can update nested state with ...
Just look at this question: [react set state in for nested state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/react-set-state-in-for-nested-state)

```
return {
    ...state,
    fetching: false,
    fetched: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Important thing to notice here (from https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. **It may
>   batch or defer the update until later**. This makes reading this.state
>   right after calling setState() a potential pitfall.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering a second time. Here's an example how to update a nested store in React:

```
    this.setState({test: {one: 'asdasdasd'}}, () => {
        let { test } = this.state
        const second = {two: 'zwei'}
        Object.assign(test, second)
        this.setState({
            test,
        }, () => {
            console.log(this.state)
        })
    })
```